# How do I return an image blob out of these nested functions

Tags: javascript, function, canvas, nested

I have been trying to return an image blob object from within these nested functions. You can see in my code that I tried the idea given [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373934/returning-values-from-nested-functions-in-javascript#answer-3373953), but did not help. Please read all the comments in the code to grasp the scenario. Please let me know if need more details.

```
function resizetoBlob(file) { //resizes given image file to blob
        var blob = "";
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function() {

            var tempImg = new Image();
            tempImg.src = reader.result;
            tempImg.onload = function() {

                    //resize calculation done here

                    var dUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg',0.8);
                    blob = dataURLtoBlob(dUrl);
                    //this is the blob object I need to return
            }
        }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    return blob; //obviously this does not work.
}
```

Here is a [link to the function](http://pastebin.com/1YQeTB0Y) dataURLtoBlob.

Comment: You can't do that. You'll have to design your API so that you pass in a callback and then invoke that from inside the "load" callback.

Comment: please post code for `dataURLtoBlob()`

Comment: @Pamblam please check the bottom of the question for a link to the code for dataurltoblob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you asyncronously load the Data Url, you cannot instantly `return blob`, instead you could perhaps pass a function as a paramater to be executed when the Data Url has finished generating. For example:

```
function resizetoBlob(file,func) { //resizes given image file to blob
    var blob = "";
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {

        var tempImg = new Image();
        tempImg.src = reader.result;
        tempImg.onload = function() {

                //resize calculation done here

                var dUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg',0.8);
                blob = dataURLtoBlob(dUrl);
                func(blob); //excute function, passing "blob" as a paramater
        }
    }
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

And then to use this function:

```
resizetoBlob(FILE,function(blob){
    //do whatever you wish with the blob
    //this function will run when the blob is loaded (i.e dataUrl)
    }
);
```

For a better understanding, and to see good clear examples of asycronous activity, check out the ["duplicate" resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).