# How to get a value out of a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the row number out of a JavaScript function:

```
function cap_check(){
    var row;

    $('td').change(function(){ 
        row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());  
        alert(row);
    }); 

    alert(row);
}
```

*Within* the function, `row` is correctly alerted. Outside of the function, it is `undefined`.

Comment: take a look at this post. it is the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611980/return-value-from-nested-function-in-javascript

Comment: could you please include the html that goes with this code

Comment: @JAiro: No, it's not the same.

Comment: What do you expect? When the function `cap_check` is called, it does not mean that the `change` event handler is triggered immediately. Meaning, `row = $(this).parent()....` will be executed some time later after `cap_check` already returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way that calling `cap_check` will ever alert anything other than `undefined`. A function is not a static object. When you call a function, it creates a new instance on the internal stack. `row` will be initialized as `undefined` and a new click handler will be bound to `td` elements (also not likely to be useful - as another duplicate event handler will be bound each time you call `cap_check`).

Most likely, you want something like this:

```
var cap_check=(function() {
    var row;
    $('td').change(function(){ 
        row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());  
        alert(row);
    }); 
    return function() {
       alert(row);
    };
}());
```

This is a self-executing function. When the script runs, the part of the function BEFORE the "return" is executed immediately, creating your event binding once, and returning a function that references the original function instance. This creates a *closure* which means that the function maintains a reference to the objects of it's parent (in this case, the `row` variable). So your event handler, and the function returned as `cap_check`, now will always refer to the same instance of `row`.

So - now any code that calls `cap_check` will always return the same value assigned as a result of the `change` event.

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/RagUe/5/

(Note that I changed the event to "click" instead of "change" to make it easily testable).

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how and why this works--is there some reading or YouTube watching material I can look at to better understand the mechanisms or concepts at work here? I'm not getting what happens when you wrap the function and other things in parens (doesn't that make a tuple?), or what is happening when the function returns a function, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`$('td').change(function(){ })`

Change allows you to pass a callback that will run whenever the value changes.

So just by attaching the callback it wont run it. It will only run when the value changes. Since the rest of the function runs before the value changes the value of `row` is undefined.

Simply place the rest of the script in the callback

Comment: He already has the callback, he just needs to keep the rest of the function within it's scope

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses guys.I tried that but it effects to some other onChange triggering in the rest of the code.That's why I need to take the value out from the jq function.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you keep the remainder of the function within the change function?

```
function cap_check(){
     var row;
             //-----------------------Jquery current table row  
     $('td').change(function(){ 
           row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());  

           //rest of script here
         }); 

 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `row` inside the function is in a completely different scope then the row outside.

So when you are outside of the `change()` function `row` is undefined, but as soon as `change` is triggered, `row` gets a value

```
function cap_check(){
    var row;

    $('td').change(function(){ 
        row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());  
        alert(row); //only has a value on change
    }); 

    alert(row); //undefined
}
```

Comment: @Raynos, whatever do you mean?

Comment: That is a too broad generalization. JavaScript is not asynchronous. Only event handlers (sort of) and Ajax. Passing a function as parameter does not imply anything about when the function will be executed.

Comment: If it's wrong do you have any other alternative ideas to get the job done to make this script function.

Comment: Yes you are correct Naal :). I mean is there any other way to get the job done.I mean to make the below code separate from the jq change function along with the row value.

Comment: @Ceylo: You have not explained us what `cap_check` is supposed to do. We can only help you if we know which problem you are trying to solve.