# Return value from nested success-function in jQuery's $.ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, nested, return-value

I found this question which is almost exactly the same: [Return value from nested function in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611980/return-value-from-nested-function-in-javascript)

The problem is that the function is passed to jQuery's `$.ajax` function. Here's what i have:

```
function doSomething() {
    // Do some stuff here
    console.log(getCartInfo());
}

function getCartInfo() {
    var url = blog_location + '?reqCartData=1';

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'get',
        success: function(data) {
            return data;  <------------- This
        }
    });
}
```

I need to return `data` to the doSomething function, if that makes sense. I tried to return the entire `$.ajax` function but that returned the whole object. Any ideas?

Comment: This is asked on a daily basis. See [How to return the response from an AJAX call from a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call-from-a-function)

Comment: @FabrícioMatté You're right, sorry. *Edit:* Voted to close!

Answer (score 0):

Send a callback function:

```
function getCartInfo(onSuccess) {
    var url = blog_location + '?reqCartData=1';

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'get',
        success: function(data) {
            onSuccess(data);
        }
    });
}

getCartInfo(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 function doSomething(date) {
    ........your data
}

function getCartInfo() {
    var url = blog_location + '?reqCartData=1';

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'get',
        success: function(data) {
           doSomething(data);
        }
    });
}
```