# How do I get geolocation to return to a variable in jquery?

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

below is some rough code I'm working on. All I'm trying to do, right now is return the var geoOutput so I can store it and use it for later. In the example it should alert the city and state. I works if I alert from within the success but returns as undefined when outside the geolocation function.

```
$(function(){
    var geoOutput;
    var geoGet;
    function getGeoLocation(geoType,displayType){
        if(navigator.geolocation){
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoError);
            }
            else {
                $('.your-location').remove();
            }
        function geoSuccess(position) {
            console.log(position.coords.latitude+', '+position.coords.longitude);
            var geoCoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var userLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
            geoCoder.geocode({'latLng':userLocation}, function(results,status){
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    if (results) {
                        if(geoType == "zip") {
                            geoOutput = results[2].address_components[0].long_name;
                        }
                        if(geoType == "state") {
                            geoOutput = results[6].address_components[0].long_name;
                        }
                        if(geoType == "city") {
                            geoOutput = results[3].address_components[0].long_name;
                        }
                        if(geoType == "cityState") {
                            geoOutput = results[3].address_components[0].long_name+", "+results[6].address_components[0].long_name;
                        }
                        if(geoType == "coords") {
                            geoOutput = position.coords.latitude+","+position.coords.longitude;
                        }
                        if(geoType == "longitude") {
                            geoOutput = position.coords.longitude;
                        }
                        if(geoType == "latitude") {
                            geoOutput = position.coords.latitude;
                        }
                        if(displayType)
                            $('.your-location').text(geoOutput);
                        return geoOutput;
                    } else {
                        console.log('Google did not return any results.');
                        $('.your-location').remove();
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Reverse Geocoding failed due to: " + status);
                    $('.your-location').remove();
                }
            });
        }
        function geoError(err) {
             if (err.code == 1) {
                //console.log('The user denied the request for location information.');
                $('.your-location').text('State Not Found');
            } else if (err.code == 2) {
                //console.log('Your location information is unavailable.');
                $('.your-location').remove();
            } else if (err.code == 3) {
                //console.log('The request to get your location timed out.');
                $('.your-location').remove();
            } else {
                //console.log('An unknown error occurred while requesting your location.');
                $('.your-location').remove();
             }
        }
    }

    alert(getGeoLocation("cityState",false));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be returning the success function itself as well. See this answer for more details about returning from a nested function: [Return value from nested function in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611980/return-value-from-nested-function-in-javascript)