# Trouble returning from inner to outer function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, return

I'm working through the book Eloquent JavaScript. One of the exercises asks you to create a recursive function that returns the nth value in a list, of the format:

```
var list = {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: {value: 30, rest: null}}};
```

I've since viewed and understood the author's solution (and I now realise I actually didn't *need* an inner function!) but I'm still curious as to why my code doesn't work:

```
function nth(list, num){
    var count = 0;
    function findNum(node){
        if(count == num){
            var result = node.value;
            console.log("From inner function: " + result);
            return result;
        }else {
            node = node.rest;
            count++
            findNum(node);
        }
    }
    var output = "From outer function: " + findNum(list);
    return output;
}
```

I've researched the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611980/return-value-from-nested-function-in-javascript) and I appear to be doing the right thing to return from the inner function, however I get the following results when the outer function is called:

```
console.log(nth({value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: {value: 30, rest: null}}}, 0));
//From inner function: 10
//From outer function: 10

console.log(nth({value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: {value: 30, rest: null}}}, 1));
//From inner function: 20
//From outer function: undefined

console.log(nth({value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: {value: 30, rest: null}}}, 2));
//From inner function: 30
//From outer function: undefined
```

My question is: why does the outer function return as intended when looking for the first value but return as 'undefined' in the other two cases?

Comment: Yeah I found a few answers about the exercise but I couldn't see one that addressed this particular problem

Comment: Nothing that could not be solved by simply walking through your code in the debugger watching what it does.

Answer (score -1):

`findNum` object returns a value only if the `if` statement matches.

In the `else` side, it calls `findNum` recursively **but ignores the return value** you get back from that call.

You have to `return` what you get back from recursively calling `findNum`