# How can I return a value from a nested function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a function:

```
function CanDisplayImage() {
  $("img").on('error', function() {
    // do stuff 
    // and finally return false
    return false;
  });
  // if there weren't any error in displaying image, return true
  return true;
}
```

That function should check whether image can display correctly or not.
I wasn't that function to return true or false, for example when I call that:

```
CanDisplayImage(); // get true or false
```

So if there weren't any error it will return true, but if there were error, it won't return false, because the function inside of that function will return false.
Do U know how can I make that work?

Comment: No, you cannot make that work. The error event is asynchronous.

Comment: Have you had a look at the following:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611980/return-value-from-nested-function-in-javascript
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993563/how-do-i-return-a-variable-from-google-maps-javascript-geocoder-callback

Comment: Thanks. That was a good solution. Now I managed to do that.